# Change an attribute in Plant 3D with data from a Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, autocad-plugin

I'm trying to change/update attributes in Plant 3d with data from a datatable specified in the Windows Form Datagridview. But it doesn't work. Can someone help me.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dtrows)
 {
     int dtPnPID = Convert.ToInt32(row["PnPID"]);
     prj.SetAcquisitionStatus(dtPnPID, "BoDoPosNr", AcquisitionStatus.Overidden);
     PnPRow row1 = db.GetRow(dtPnPID);
     

     row1.BeginEdit();
     row1["BoDoPosNr"] = row["PosNr"];
     row1.EndEdit();
     dlm.AcceptChanges();
     
 }
```